# Kibana Timelion not showing any data

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to visualize my data with Kibana.
When I go to `Discover` tab I see all data, and data comes in real-time mode:

```
{
  "_index": "bio-input",
  "_type": "meas-kafka_filtered",
  "_id": "bio-input+0+1379",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "org": "TEST",
    "account_id": "EE11CBB19052E40B07AAC0CA060C23EE",
    "timestamp": 1516362003643,
    "o2": 0.6,
    "temperature": 36.6
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1516362003643
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1516362003643
  ]
}
```

But when I try to visualize it - I have got a clear chart on 'Visualize' tab. My Timelion Expression is

```
.es(index=bio-input,metric=avg:o2,timefield=@timestamp)
```

Elasticsearch and Kibana version - `6.1.2`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I copied and modified it for my fields and it worked. Did you check the timewindow(usual top right corner to specify), would it show data?

Comment: Yes, I did it. But it still does not work for me

Comment: I don't know what to say, I made the exact copy and it works for me in Timelion. What if you change the o2 field to temperature?

Comment: The same. Looks like something wrong with the @timestamp field. This is 'scripted' field because original timestamp field is in long format.

Comment: Is it date type?

Comment: I you mean @timestamp field - yes

Comment: Can you use `timefield=timestamp` instead of `timefield=@timestamp`. Any difference?

Comment: When I use timestamp (Long) - I have got an error: the type of timefield must be Date

Comment: @TarasSheremeta  I have the same issue as you, did u found a solution, please ?!!

Answer (score 0):

You must have set the timestamp field as a format that could be parsed. The timestamp should not be "long" datatype. It has to be on "date" datatype only then you can plot them in timelions.
Or If your data is in the correct timestamp format and you have the right date time window still it does not show then try specifically going to the exact day because if the data is too less then the graph could look empty compared to the whole scale.